# Get the last 5 results of column C or D if column A or B is equal to ___?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, average, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I know the title is a horrible description, sorry.

Basically I have a sheet with results from basketball games. So in column A I have the home team. In column B I have the away team. In column C the home team's points. In column D the away team's points. There's about 500 rows worth of data at the minute.

What I want to do is the following:

Say I want to get the average points scored by the New York Knicks in their last 5 games. The most recent games are at the bottom of the sheet, and the first/oldest ones at the top of the sheet.

So across the bottom/last 5 instances of "New York Knicks" in column A and B, I want the average of the results of C (if New York Knicks is in column A) and D (if in column B).

I know how to do this if I would want just the last 5 home games for instance (so in that instance I basically query the bottom 5 results of column C in the last 5 occurrences of column A being New York Knicks). I don't know how to do it when I am looking for when New York Knicks occurs in either column A or B, and then have to get the averages from column C or D.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you tried averageifs()? That would be my first attempt.

Comment: I don't think averageifs() allow me to take the last ___ number of results, it just calculates the column based on what range I put in. I don't want to manually adjust the range every time to get last ___ number of results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will transform your 4 columns into 2 columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A2:B<>"", "♠"&A2:B&"♦"&C2:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"))
```

[image: 0]

and average score of the last 5 games:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AVERAGE(QUERY(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(A2:B<>"", "♠"&A2:B&"♦"&C2:D, )),,999^99)),,999^99), "♠")), "♦"), 
 "select Col2 
  where lower(Col1) contains 'new york knicks' 
  offset "&COUNTIF(A2:B, "new york knicks")-5)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks How would you then use this to do points against? Ie when New York Knicks is column A I want column D, and when NYK is column B I'd want column C, for calculating points against. Can't figure out how to edit the first formula you sent to get this.

Comment: not sure I understand what are you after... can you explain in more detail? do you want an average of scores of last 5 events of whatever team played against NYK?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is there a way to do this similar to your first formula?

Comment: sure, just switch the columns. instead of `C2:D` use `{D2:D,C2:C}`

Comment: Last one. How do I edit the original formula to include both points for and points against? So that it would have the team in column A, then points for in column B, and points against in column C? In the original formula you showed how to do the A+B column part of it and that is working. How do I adjust the formula so that the column C result also gets output (points scored against), the D2:D, C2:C thing?

Comment: see G2: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QiU7hzjIbcDn19_qnFmHu-eSMLeA_UML9DwaTXruppc/edit#gid=260519771

Comment: Hey - thanks again for the help. One other question I've run into. If I have column A and B with the team names, and in column E I have a formula that gives TRUE/FALSE as the output...if I want to count how many times in the last 5 games of New York Knicks that column E returns TRUE, how would I do that? I tried changing some of the formulas you gave into COUNTIFS instead of AVERAGE but couldn't figure it out. You can edit that spreadsheet you linked above if you like to send the formula.